# How to implement a custom_access_token_expires_in method with Doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-api, doorkeeper

I have a rails 7 application with its own api. I am using Doorkeeper gem to implement authorizing external parties to be able to use the API.

So far I have gotten the Doorkeeper gem working with the following workflow:

- User creates a new application with `Doorkeeper::Application` and receives a `client_id` and `client_secret`.
- User logs in using the endpoint `/api/v1/oauth/token` and with the follow params:

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "password": "password",
    "client_id": "laksjdflkajfljlkjdsalkjdas",
    "client_secret": "dasldjaskdjaslkdjaslkdjalk",
}
```

responds with:

```
{
    "access_token": "sdadasdasdasdasdasdasd",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "created_at": 1662501786
}
```

**Question: How do I structure my Doorkeeper initializer to have an access token that expires in 2 hours and another access token that expires in 1 year?**

I create the access token here:

```
module DoorkeeperRegisterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  #   def generate_refresh_token
  #     loop do
  #       token = SecureRandom.hex(32)
  #       break token unless Doorkeeper::AccessToken.exists?(refresh_token: token)
  #     end
  #   end

  def render_user(user, client_app, token_type = 'Bearer')
    access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create(
      resource_owner_id: user.id,
      application_id: client_app.id,
      #   refresh_token: generate_refresh_token,
      expires_in: Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_expires_in.to_i,
      scopes: ''
    )

    {
      id: user.id,
      access_token: access_token.token,
      token_type:,
      expires_in: access_token.expires_in,
      #   refresh_token: access_token.refresh_token,
      created_at: access_token.created_at.to_time.to_i
    }
  end
end
```

I can change the value of `access_token_expires_in 2.hours` in `config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb` but cannot get a second option to work.

I tried doing this in `config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb`:

```
custom_access_token_expires_in do |context|
 return 1.year if context
end
```

and then trying to access it in the concern by doing:

```
Doorkeeper.configuration.custom_access_token_expires_in.to_i
```

but cannot get it to work. I dont think I am understanding `context` in the initilizer file correctly. No matter what I try it defaults to the value of `access_token_expires_in`.

The goal I would like to acheive is to have `access_token_expires_in 2.hours` for when the user tries getting a token without a password. And when a user sends a password param with a correct password, I somehow use `custom_access_token_expires_in` to send an access token that takes longer to expire. This is probably me misunderstanding how Doorkeeper works but if anyone is able to help me build out this workflow I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was confusing endpoints. The concerned I linked was for my `create` user endpoint.

All I needed to do was add this to doorkeeper.rb initializer:

```
  custom_access_token_expires_in do |context|
    if context.grant_type == "password"
      2.years
    else
      1.day
    end
  end
```

Essentially this checks the params for a valid `password` grant type. If the grant type is valid (and so is the password) the access token will expire in 2 years, otherwise if no `password` grant type is passed by the request is authorized it will be one day